# Vue warn]: Property or method "productos" is not defined on the instance but referenced during

Tags: vue.js, axios, data

Hola soy nueva en Vue y Laravel, estoy intentando realizar un catalogo de productos y tengo algunas rutas vue en el menu principal de mi sitio, quiero que en una de los pestañas del menú en este caso en 'card' se muestre el listado de productos, para lo cual tengo el siguiente código:

**Card.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="mt-5">
         <tr :v-for="prod in productos" key="prod">
          <td>@{{ prod.id_producto }}</td>
          <td>@{{ prod.nombre }}</td>
        </tr>
      </div>
    </template>
    <script>
    export default {
      name: "card",
      data: {
        productos: [],
      },
      created: function () {
        this.getProductos();
      },
      methods: {
        getProductos: function () {
          var url = "/Producto";
          axios
            .get(url)
            .then((response) => {
              this.productos = response.data;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              (error) => (this.status = error.response.data.status);
              console.log(error.response.data);
              console.log(error.response.status);
              console.log(error.response.headers);
            });
        },
      },
    };
    </script>***
```

**Controlador: ProductoController.php**

```
 <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    use App\bp_productos;
    
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    
    class ProductoController extends Controller
    {
        //
        public function index()
        {               
            $productos=bp_productos::all();
            return $productos;
        
        }
       
    }
```

Obtengo los siguientes mensajes de error:
[image: error]

Comment: No sé si esté relacionado al error que mustras, pero en un componente la propiedad data debe ser una función que retorne un objeto. Dale una mirada a cómo está explicado en la documentación de Vue https://es.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Debe-ser-una-funcion

Answer (score 0):

Resuelto:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "card",
  data: function () {
    return {
      symbols: [],
    };
  },
  created: function () {
    axios
      .get("Producto")
      .then((response) => (this.symbols = response.data))
      .catch((error) => {
        (error) => (this.status = error.response.data.status);
        console.log(error.response.data);
        console.log(error.response.status);
        console.log(error.response.headers);
      });
  },

};
</script>
```